# Update of complex object fails in DB context

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to update only object MwbePaymentMethod's simple properties,  without complex properties (4 last properties are complex), so it changes these 4 complex properties to unchanged. But method Edit fails in line:

```
  Context.Entry(payment.BillingAddress).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

with error:

Attaching an entity of type 'MobileWallet.Common.Repository.MwbeAddress' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

Model object:

```
 public class MwbePaymentMethod : BaseEntity
    {
        public enum MethodTypeEnum
        {
            Creditcard,
            Virtualcard,
            Wallet
        };
        public MethodTypeEnum MethodType { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ExpirationDate { get; set; }
        public double Balance { get; set; }
        public bool IsPending { get; set; }
        public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
        public MwbeAddress BillingAddress { get; set; }
        public MwbeCurrency Currency { get; set; }
        public MwbeUserData UserData { get; set; }
        public DateTime? PaymentDate { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<MwbePayment> Payments { get; set; }
    }
```

Edit method:

```
public override void Edit(MwbePaymentMethod payment)
        {

            if (payment.Currency != null && payment.Currency.Id != 0)
            {
                Context.Entry(payment.Currency).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            }
            if (payment.UserData != null && payment.UserData.Id != 0)
            {
                Context.Entry(payment.UserData).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            }

            if (payment.BillingAddress != null && payment.BillingAddress.Id != 0)
            {
                Debugger.Break(); 
                Context.Entry(payment.BillingAddress).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            }

            Context.Entry(payment).State = EntityState.Modified;
            if (Context.Entry(payment).State == EntityState.Detached)
            {
                DbSet.Attach(payment);
            }
        }
```

ADDED1:

I changed code a bit, Im reading all Navigation fields/object especially for Billing Address which was not fully filled with the same data as they were in database.

```
 public void UpdateMwbePaymentMethod(MwbePaymentMethodFilter filter, MwbePaymentMethodDtoInOut mwbepaymentmethod)
        {
            var currentPaymentMethod = paymentMethodRepository.FindBy(x => x.UserData.Id == filter.userId && x.Id == filter.id);
            if (currentPaymentMethod == null || currentPaymentMethod.Count() != 1)
            {
                throw new DBConcurrencyException();
            }
            var mwbePaymentPethod = Mapper.Map<MwbePaymentMethod>(mwbepaymentmethod);

            //load existing user data
            mwbePaymentPethod.UserData = userRepository.Get(filter.userId).Data;

            //load existing address with subproperties
            mwbePaymentPethod.BillingAddress = addressRepository.FindBy(x => x.Id == mwbePaymentPethod.BillingAddress.Id, x=>x.Merchants, x=>x.PaymentMethods, x=>x.Deliveries, x=>x.UserDatas).SingleOrDefault();

            if (mwbePaymentPethod.BillingAddress == null)
            {
                throw new DBConcurrencyException();
            }

            paymentMethodRepository.Edit(mwbePaymentPethod);
            paymentMethodRepository.SaveChanges();
        }
```

And Edit method:

```
public override void Edit(MwbePaymentMethod payment)
    {

        if (payment.Currency != null && payment.Currency.Id != 0)
        {
            Context.Entry(payment.Currency).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        }
        if (payment.UserData != null && payment.UserData.Id != 0)
        {
            Context.Entry(payment.UserData).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        }

        if (payment.BillingAddress != null && payment.BillingAddress.Id != 0)
        {
            Debugger.Break(); // tutaj byl ostatnio problem
            Context.Entry(payment.BillingAddress).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        }
        Context.Entry(payment).State = EntityState.Modified;

    }
```

No matter if

1)    `Context.Entry(payment.BillingAddress).State = EntityState.Unchanged;`

or

2) `Context.Entry(payment.BillingAddress).State = EntityState.Modified;`

Still the same error is displayed. For me point 2) should work if I didnt attached all properties from db, but it's not working.

Comment: I've answered why you are having problems while trying to change the state of complex types. I've just noticed another problem with your code. When you do this `Context.Entry(payment).State = EntityState.Modified;` you effectively make the line below `if (Context.Entry(payment).State == EntityState.Detached)` to be always false. An entity cannot be in two states at the same time (you are testing the same property, the one you've just changed).

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

Complex types are not entities, therefore they are not tracked. The entity they belong to is.

To understand why this makes sense think about it this way:
Your MwbePaymentMethod has an Address which is a complex type. In the database they will be stored in one table, the (default) column names will be:
Number, MwbeAddress_Line1, MwbeAddress_Line2, MwbeAddress_PostalCode, ...

If you change Line1 of the address, the whole MwbePaymentMethod table's row in the database needs to be updated. In fact, if you change any value of any complex property that belongs to the entity MwbePaymentMethod that will lead to an update to the whole entity (because in the end they all belong to the same table in the DB).

This is why it does not make sense to "update only object MwbePaymentMethod's simple properties, without [updating the] complex properties".

You can only change the state (Context.Entry(Entity).State = ...) of the entities in DbSets in your context (i.e. all the X in DbSet in your Context class)

See [**this**](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-2-complex-types). Specifically the section named: Complex Types: Splitting a Table Across Multiple Types

Answer (score 0):

In the first line of your edit code attach the entity to the context:

```
DbSet.Attach(payment);
```

*NOTE:* `DbSet` doesn't have an static `Attach` method. It should be the `DbSet<MwbePaymentMethod >` property defined in your context.

Once you've done it, set the state of the payment to modified:

```
Context.Entry(payment).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Then set the state of all the other entities. Take into account that, when you attach a tree to the context, it's attached in the unchanged state. From MSDN Attach docs:

> Attach is used to repopulate a context with an entity that is known to already exist in the database. SaveChanges will therefore not attempt to insert an attached entity into the database because it is assumed to already be there. Note that entities that are already in the context in some other state will have their state set to Unchanged. Attach is a no-op if the entity is already in the context in the Unchanged state.

So you have to attach to the context, and then change the state to smething else, like added, when necessary. You're doing the contrary.

And finally verify that the `payment` object has the correct id. If it's not there, you must include it in a hidden field or any other form input, so that it's posted back to the server.

Comment: Thanks for answer:): 1) In real im using internal DbSet<TEntity> DbSet, so DB set is strongly-typed. 2) I dont undestand, Im attaching object which is modified, but error is that sub-object MwbeAddress is already in system. But I didn change it and just want to change it to Unchanged.... to not udpate this object in DB.... I dont understand your explanation